Using Infineon-S70FL01GS_1_Gbit(Serial Flash Memory) has problem. Can't read Device ID
I try to using serial flash memory Infineon-S70FL01GS_1_Gbit.
It's a flash memory that has been in use for a long time and seems to work fine with existing code(Using IAR). But, now I try to refactoring code and using STM32CubeIDE.
MCU and Flash memory schematic is same and SPI and other CS pin and WP pin setting same.
But the new code has problem to read device ID. Device ID should read 0x19, but it reads 0x00 or 0xFF.
This is old code and scope capture image.
void Hal_SPIInit(void) {
  SPI_InitTypeDef    SPI_InitStructure;
  GPIO_InitTypeDef   GPIO_InitStructure;

  EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

  //SPI3 INIT
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(HAL_SPI3_CLK, ENABLE);

  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(HAL_SF_SPI3_CLK, ENABLE);

  /* Configure SPI3 SCK pin */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = HAL_SPI3_SCK_PIN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_Init(HAL_SPI3_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Configure SPI3 MISO pin */
  //GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD; //GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = HAL_SPI3_MISO_PIN;
  GPIO_Init(HAL_SPI3_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Configure SPI3 MOSI pin */
  //GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = HAL_SPI3_MOSI_PIN;
  GPIO_Init(HAL_SPI3_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Connect SPI3 SCK */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(HAL_SPI3_PORT, HAL_SPI3_SCK_SOURCE, HAL_SPI3_AF);

  /* Connect SPI3 MISO */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(HAL_SPI3_PORT, HAL_SPI3_MISO_SOURCE, HAL_SPI3_AF);

  /* Connect SPI3 MOSI */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(HAL_SPI3_PORT, HAL_SPI3_MOSI_SOURCE, HAL_SPI3_AF);

  //SPI_I2S_DeInit(HAL_SF_SPI3);        // Removed by Seo 20161005 only for test

  /* SPI3 Config */
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_High;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_8;   // if 8: SPC 5.2MHz; 16: SPC 2.6MHz
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
  SPI_Init(HAL_SF_SPI3, &SPI_InitStructure);

//  /* Configure the RX FIFO Threshold */
//  SPI_RxFIFOThresholdConfig(HAL_SF_SPI3, SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_QF);        // Added by Seo 20161005 only for test

  /* SPI3 enable */
  SPI_Cmd(HAL_SF_SPI3, ENABLE);  
  
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(HAL_FLASH_CS_GPIO_CLK, ENABLE);
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = HAL_FLASH_CS_GPIO_PIN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_Init(HAL_FLASH_CS_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  FLASH_NSS_HIGH();             // this is used for Accel's CS pin on H/W Rev.C because of H/W error

  HalMCUDelayMs(100);
}




void HalSFlashInit(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(HAL_FLASH_CS_GPIO_CLK, ENABLE);

  /* Flash NSS_CS  */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = HAL_FLASH_CS_GPIO_PIN|HAL_FLASH_CS2_GPIO_PIN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_Init(HAL_FLASH_CS_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(HAL_FLASH_WP_GPIO_CLK, ENABLE);

  /* Flash WP   */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = HAL_FLASH_WP_GPIO_PIN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_Init(HAL_FLASH_WP_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_SetBits(HAL_FLASH_WP_GPIO_PORT, HAL_FLASH_WP_GPIO_PIN);

  HalSFlashS70FLxInit(0);
  HalSFlashS70FLxInit(1);
}

int HalSFlashS70FLxInit(uint8_t deviceId)
{
  static uint8_t devID, statReg1, statReg2;
  _device_id = deviceId;

  SLLD_STATUS status = slld_Read_IDCmd(&devID);
  Hal_DebugPrint("device %d id 0x%x\n",deviceId,devID);
  if(status != SLLD_OK)
    return HAL_EINVALID_STATE;

  //check block protection
  slld_RDSRCmd(&statReg1);
  slld_RDSR2Cmd(&statReg2);

  if(devID != HAL_SF_DEV_ID)
    return HAL_EINVALID_CONFIG;
  else
    return HAL_SUCCESS;
}

enter image description here
Old Code(IAR)
This is new code and capture image.
void MX_SPI3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 1 */
  hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
  hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi3.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8;
  hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 2 */

}

void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* spiHandle){
  else if(spiHandle->Instance==SPI3)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_MspInit 0 */
    /* SPI3 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI3_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**SPI3 GPIO Configuration
    PB5     ------> SPI3_MOSI
    PB4     ------> SPI3_MISO
    PB3     ------> SPI3_SCK
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* SPI3 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI3_IRQn, 5, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI3_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_MspInit 1 */
  }
}


void FLASHUser::lazyInit() {
  set_cs1();
  set_cs2();
  enable_wp();
}

void FLASHUser::check_dev_0_id() {
  uint8_t temp_dev_id = 0;

  enable_cs1();
  slld_Read_IDCmd(&temp_dev_id);
  disable_all();

  printf("device 0 dev id : 0x%02X\n", temp_dev_id);

}

enter image description here
New Code(STM32CubeIDE)
In new code, read device ID twice, second read device ID command is response 0x19. But still write command is not working.
How to fix it??
I expect read and write collectly like old code.
